# Adding column to dataframes based on variable name

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to add a two columns to each dataframe based on their name before concatenating all of them. One column is year and the other is trimester.   So t1_15  would be trimester 1  and year 2015.

I tried building a function that did it in one go but due to time constraints just ended up doing it manually like this.  I'm now returning to this problem with more time and would really like to sort it out.

```
frames_15 = [t1_15, t2_15, t3_15, t4_15]
for i in frames_15:
    i['year'] = 2015

frames_16 = [t1_16, t2_16, t3_16, t4_16]
for i in frames_16:
    i['year'] = 2016

frames_17 = [t1_17, t2_17, t3_17]
for i in frames_17:
    i['year'] = 2017

frames_trim_1 = [t1_15, t1_16, t1_17]
for i in frames_trim_1:
    i['trimestre'] = 1

frames_trim_2 = [t2_15, t2_16, t2_17]
for i in frames_trim_2:
    i['trimestre'] = 2

frames_trim_3 = [t3_15, t3_16, t3_17]
for i in frames_trim_3:
    i['trimestre'] = 3

frames_trim_4 = [t4_15, t4_16]
for i in frames_trim_4:
    i['trimestre'] = 4
```

id like each df to have a year and trimester column based on its name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does your input data look like ?

Comment: are you trying to create a dataframe that has 3 columns (name, year, trimester), passing as name all of the frames?

Comment: Each element  tx_xx in these lists is a dataframe of its own with hundreds of columns and thousands of rows.  But no variable to identify the trimester or year.  

Sorry if that was confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to build a dictionary, where you register your dataframes. You already gave them names according to their assignment to a trimester.
If you already know these infos by the time of creation, you could even register these dataframes in a dictionary, whose keys are tuples of trimester and year.

If you have something like in your description, you could also use the globals dictionary, but this is not quite clean and should be regarded as last choice in case there is no cleaner way.

If you build up your dictionary with keys named like the variable names above, or if you want to use the globals dictionary direclty, you could do it as follows:

```
import re
df_directory= dict(globals())
name_re= re.compile('^t([0-9])_([0-9]{2})$')
for name, df in df_directory.items():
    matcher= name_re.match(name)
    if matcher and isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
        trimester, year= matcher.groups()
        df['trimestre']= int(trimester)
        df['year']= int(year) + 2000
```

This processes all variables named by the schema tX_XX and of type DataFrame and parses the trimester and year out of the name to assign it to columns each.